# What is difference between Exploratory Testing and Rapid Testing

Tags: manual-testing, exploratory

A couple of days back I come across one Term "Rapid Testing" I try to understand about it but it's all properties are same as Exploratory Testing. can you please tell me the difference between these two type of testing.

Comment: Where did you hear about the term Rapid Testing? As a part of a course called Rapid Software Testing? From James Bach? Or is it a general term you heard about?

Answer (score 4):

Rapid Testing is a strategy where you test a product quickly to meet extremely short product delivery schedules, by eliminating all unnecessary work and only testing critical areas of the product. Instead of trying to eliminate all bugs, the rapid testing ethos is to stop 'damaging defects' from being released.

Rapid Testing is therefore the terminology given to testing a product at a rapid pace, by only testing key sections of the product. This strategy will then consist of testing methods such as exploratory testing, isolated smoke tests, unplanned end-to-end tests, etc...

Answer (score 2):

**Exploratory Testing:** Exploratory testing is a advanced form of ad-hoc testing. Today  most of the QA testing companies performs exploratory testing to explore and learn the new feature of the product of which no specification of the functionality and documentation is available.

**Rapid testing** perform by QA in Software testing company in a situation where there is requirement of validation of application in short time and we need to deliver the results accurately within that short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Same technique but with minor differences:

What they have in common:

- With little test plan, testers start testing using their common sense and prior experience.

What they have in difference:

- As its name suggests, rapid testing focuses on "fastness". James Bach is one of the testers that promote rapid testing. Please follow this link [Rapid testing by James Bach](http://www.satisfice.com/info_rst.shtml)

Comment: James Bach & Michael Bolton call their (trademarked) course Rapid Software Testing. Which is also a testing methodology. However I can't tell if the person asking is referring to this or some general term. Do you know? =)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. James Bach's TM Rapid Software Testing is based on Rapid Testing methodology. In this case, these two terms are interchangeable.

Comment: RST and the RST methodology are one thing. It would be good to know if that's what the asking person is referring to, or if he/she is thinking of something more generic like "testing rapidly".

Comment: @ChrisKenst, true, good point.